# Возможно ли с помощью PHP или JavaSciprt строку перенаправить в PSD

Tags: javascript, php, python, html, dompdf

Хочу сразу предупредить: я знаю про Dompdf. Но у меня вопрос такой: есть готовый макет из psd, там есть формы поля ввода. Я создал этот макет с помощью html и css. Хотел бы узнать, есть ли такая возможность: когда кто-то наберет какой-то текст (в форме html,css), этот текст появлялся и на макаете psd. То есть, допустим, я написал "привет", нажал на кнопку, и после этого у меня открылся макет psd и там появился мой текст "привет" Возможно ли это реализовать с помощью php или javascript или на другом языке?

Comment: Вы не пробовали пользоваться знаками препинания?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно. Вам надо разобрать PSD-файл и внести в него изменения. Формат файла описан в https://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/. Задачка не из лёгких, но возможно её уже кто-то решил. PHP решения попробуйте поискать в packagist'е.

В англоязычном стэковерфлоу [предлагают](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850899/editing-photoshop-psd-text-layers-programmatically) решения на [js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/psd-cli) и [питоне](http://techarttiki.blogspot.com/2008/08/photoshop-scripting-with-python.html).

Кстати у Adobe есть [API](https://www.adobe.io/apis/creativecloud/photo-imaging-api.html)! Правда, пока в бете.